# redis socket file disappears after reboot?

Tags: redis

I installed redis and I am setting it to use a socket.

It works fine at the beginning but if I reboot the machine (ubuntu 14.04 via vagrant on virtualbox), Redis does not start anymore and displays this error in the log: `Opening socket: bind: No such file or directory`

When I look where the socket file is supposed to be, I understand the error message since the socket file is not there anymore.
Actually, the whole `/var/run/redis` directory does not exist anymore after I reboot.

Here is what I have in my config file:

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379.
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
port 0

bind 127.0.0.1

unixsocket /var/run/redis/0.sock
unixsocketperm 755
```

Why would the socket file disappear?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK A socket only exists as long as the application is listening, it will be recreated when redis restarts. Depending on the Linux distribution /var/run may be cleaned on start-up, including a `mkdir -p /var/run/redis` in the start-up script should solve that

Comment: Oh ok, I thought /var/run was the right place to put the sockets. Where should I put the sockets? In /tmp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you are using ubuntu or some distro that mounts /var/run as tmpfs. So each reboot /var/run is cleaned out.

Run `mount` and if it lists /var/run seperately then that is the case

Comment: You're right, /var/run folder is a symlink to the /run folder and when I run ```mount```, I get ```tmpfs on /run type tmpfs```.
Where should I put the socket for redis? I also created a redis user so it has to be somewhere where this user can have access. Thanks

Comment: best bet is to edit the init script to create the socket file once redis starts